# ggparcoord: color using discrete scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, ggally

I cannot seem to get my `ggparcoord` plot to color using a discrete scale. When I do this:

```
ggparcoord(data = iris, columns = 1:4, groupColumn = "Species")
```

the output plot is still coloring the lines using a continuous scale (using the levels of the `Species` factor).

[image]

I've also tried a modified version of the the `scale_color_manual` trick specified here: [controlling color in ggparcoord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849963/controlling-color-in-ggparcoord-from-ggally-package), to no avail.

```
ggparcoord(data = iris, columns = 1:4, groupColumn = "Species") + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c("setosa" = "red", 
                                  "versicolor" = "green", 
                                  "virginica" = "blue"))
```

But I get this error message: `Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale`.

I've also tried `.. + scale_color_discrete()`: same error message.

I'm stumped... even the examples on the [ggparcorod cran page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GGally/GGally.pdf) aren't working:

```
data(diamonds, package="ggplot2")
diamonds.samp <- diamonds[sample(1:dim(diamonds)[1],100),]
ggparcoord(data = diamonds.samp,columns = c(1,5:10),groupColumn = 2)
```

Error message: `Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

**Edit**

There is a solution to this which is to use `mapping=aes(color=as.factor(Species))`, as shown in [Didzis Elferts'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1857266/didzis-elferts) answer below. But, it requires adding some further customizations in `scale_color_discrete`

```
ggparcoord(data = iris, columns = 1:4, mapping=aes(color=as.factor(Species))) +
        scale_color_discrete("Species", labels=levels(iris$Species) )
```

**Is there a method of accomplishing the same thing *without* needing to add the `scale_color_discrete("Species", labels=levels(iris$Species) )` part**?

[image]

For example, in `ggplot2`,

```
ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width,y=Sepal.Length,color=Species)) + geom_point()
```

automatically generates nicely labeled legends. Is there an analogous method in `ggparcoord`?

I am using R version 3.2.1, `ggplot2_2.0.0`, and `GGally_1.0.0`

```
sessionInfo()
# R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
# Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
# Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)
# 
# locale:
# [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
# 
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# 
# other attached packages:
# [1] ggplot2_2.0.0 GGally_1.0.0  magrittr_1.5  dplyr_0.4.3
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution is to use argument `mapping=` and set it to `as.factor(Species)` (without `as.factor()` it gives the same result as in question). Then with `scale_color_discrete()` you can get `Species` names as labels.

```
ggparcoord(data = iris, columns = 1:4, mapping=aes(color=as.factor(Species)))+
  scale_color_discrete("Species",labels=levels(iris$Species))
```

[image]

Comment: That did it, thanks! I'm a bit unhappy abou all the extra custom 'fixes' necessary in `scale_color_discrete` though. Is there no default method to generate discrete color scales directly in `ggparcord` that have the same logical defaults as `ggplot2` plots? (That is, `ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width,y=Sepal.Length,color=Species)) + geom_point()` instantly gives me a similar legend to the above without needing to specify all those extra settings...)

Comment: @adilapapaya I don't know why this happens. I just tried some code that worked.

Comment: do you mean `ggparcoord(data = iris, columns = 1:4, mapping=aes(color=as.factor(Species)))` worked out of the box for you to generate the graph above?

Comment: Yes, I red in help file of function that you can use argument `mapping=` to provide `aes()` argument and tried different solusions.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my question. If nobody else is able to answer that portion, I'll accept this answer. (Thanks for the help!)